# How to display any number to 5 decimal places

Tags: java, android

1. how to display any number to 5 decimal places. 
   for example 0.0 to 0.00000, 12.63 to 12.63000.
2. how to display any number to length 8. 
   for example 12.1 to 12.10000, 2.1234567 to 2.123456

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 9):

```
String.format("%.5f", 12.63)
```

returns 12.63000, etc

Answer (score 1):

```
double number = (long) (number * 1e5) / 1e5;
```

or

```
double number = (long) (number * 1e8) / 1e8;
```

Comment: You can add 0.5 for rounding, or use Math.round instead of casting.

Answer (score 1):

```
double value = 12.6357652133
value =Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.########").format(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

check the length of the number. If the length is less than five or eight, concatenate the necessary amount of zeros. If the length is greater than five or eight, use the substring method. Hope this helps

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "length of the number"?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. you will find the builtin function to format decimal number.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29